# Just being Curious

Tags: python

So I'v been learning how to program for about a month now. I just finished reading 'Invent your own games with python'. Before the book I had never seen a line of code. After reading the book I'm able to read code and understand what's going on. But that's about it. I got the syntax down and can use all the flow statements. I'm still not able to create my own projects and when I try to do a challenge online, I just sit there and stare at it not knowing where to start. Is this normal? Is this one of those things where one day I'm gonna wake up and It's gonna click in head. Any suggestions as too what I can do accelerate my learning?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've reached the bliss point between knowing how to write Python and how to actually program.

Python is the tool, programming is the practice.

I was in your shoes a few months ago (I had finished Data Structures and Algorithms in Python, also a good book). I decided to look online for areas to practice and understand programming problems as well as improve my math skills (math shortcuts come in handy). Nothing really clicks until you've gotten a few projects accomplished.

Designing a game IS HARD and it may not be the best place to start but if that's where you want thing to click I'd highly recommend breaking games down as a programmer might: take a feature of a game, say SimCity's Sim.
What features in OOP terms does this feature have as attributes?
What does the object do?
What external classes/objects affect this object?
What does this object externally impact?

Since you're learning Python, learning how to use the OOP paradigm is crucial and designing projects around it allow you to use Python with greater strength.

It's absolutely normal to look at a problem and have no idea where to start.
That's a lack of experience. Get some.
This is where I start if I want to get a feeler for a new language: https://projecteuler.net/

There's plenty of resources online to test your skills and there's probably an offline community near you.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any other books for beginners, don't have to be related to games. When would say is good time to tackle Django?

Comment: **Data Structures and Algorithms in Python** is a great text.
Teaches things liked Linked Lists (and how they differ from arrays) and other underlying data structures Python uses (another languages as well).

Django is a monster if you haven't worked in the MVC paradigm before. I'd recommend starting w/ Flask or Bottle if you want to do web development in the short term.
Flask is easy to learn. Django is full-featured and a bit more intensive.
Get a website under your belt in one of the easier MVC libraries then jump to Django is what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly normal for any beginner.
What you need to do is just continue doing what you are doing.
The beginning will be difficult learning curve so aim for more beginner/basic level questions (i.e.: beginner level online challenges).
Develop plenty of your own programs for fun and whenever you get stuck ask online.
When other people answer your questions online look for the most elegant solutions (i.e.: quickest execution time, neat coding style, etc...) and try remember their solutions.

The fastest way (in my opinion) to learn code is to build your own programs for fun. Just never give up no matter how hard and frustrated it gets.